# Read Audio File For Web-Audio API Analyzer (Node.Js server, JS Frontend)

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-audio-api

I set up a simple Node.js server to serve a .wav file to my local frontend.

```
require('dotenv').config();
const debugBoot = require('debug')('boot');
const cors = require('cors')
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.static('public'));


const server = app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
    const port = server.address().port;
    debugBoot('Server running at http://localhost:' + port);
});
```

On my local frontend I receive the file:

```
fetch('http://localhost:3000/audio/8bars60bpmOnlyKick.wav').then(response => process(response.body))

function process(stream) {
    console.log(stream);
    const context = new AudioContext();
    const analyser = context.createAnalyser();
    const source = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
    source.connect(analyser);
    const data = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
```

I want to pipe the stream into `AudioContext().createMediaStreamSource`. I could do this with a [Media Stream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream), e.g., from the microphone.

But with the ReadableStream, I get the error `Failed to execute 'createMediaStreamSource' on 'AudioContext': parameter 1 is not of type 'MediaStream'`.

I want to serve/receive the audio in a way that I can plug it into the web-audio API and use the analyzer. It wouldn't need to be a stream if there is a nother solution.

Comment: Have you tried looking into the `response` object being returned in the `.then(response => ...)`? This should be an object and not the stream you're looking for. You might need to use the [`response.blob()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/blob) to get the actual stream.

Comment: In the `response` object is just meta info like headers etc. `response.blob()` throws in the same error as described above.

Comment: I made an edit with my current solution. I think I'm pretty close to the final solution but I need to separate the channels.

Answer (score 2):

I merged basically those both examples together:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hYNJGPnmwls (https://codepen.io/jakealbaugh/pen/jvQweW/)

and the example from the web-audio api:

https://github.com/mdn/webaudio-examples/blob/master/audio-analyser/index.html

```
let audioBuffer;
let sourceNode;
let analyserNode;
let javascriptNode;
let audioData = null;
let audioPlaying = false;
let sampleSize = 1024;  // number of samples to collect before analyzing data
let frequencyDataArray;     // array to hold time domain data
// Global Variables for the Graphics
let canvasWidth = 512;
let canvasHeight = 256;
let ctx;

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    ctx = document.body.querySelector('canvas').getContext("2d");
    // the AudioContext is the primary 'container' for all your audio node objects
    try {
        audioContext = new AudioContext();
    } catch (e) {
        alert('Web Audio API is not supported in this browser');
    }
    // When the Start button is clicked, finish setting up the audio nodes, play the sound,
    // gather samples for the analysis, update the canvas
    document.body.querySelector('#start_button').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // Set up the audio Analyser, the Source Buffer and javascriptNode
        initCanvas();
        setupAudioNodes();
        javascriptNode.onaudioprocess = function () {
            // get the Time Domain data for this sample
            analyserNode.getByteFrequencyData(frequencyDataArray);
            // draw the display if the audio is playing
            console.log(frequencyDataArray)
            draw();
        };
        loadSound();
    });

    document.body.querySelector("#stop_button").addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        sourceNode.stop(0);
        audioPlaying = false;
    });

    function loadSound() {
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/audio/8bars60bpmOnlyKick.wav').then(response => {
            response.arrayBuffer().then(function (buffer) {
                audioContext.decodeAudioData(buffer).then((audioBuffer) => {
                    console.log('audioBuffer', audioBuffer);
                    // {length: 1536000, duration: 32, sampleRate: 48000, numberOfChannels: 2}
                    audioData = audioBuffer;
                    playSound(audioBuffer);
                });
            });
        })
    }

    function setupAudioNodes() {
        sourceNode = audioContext.createBufferSource();
        analyserNode = audioContext.createAnalyser();
        analyserNode.fftSize = 4096;
        javascriptNode = audioContext.createScriptProcessor(sampleSize, 1, 1);
        // Create the array for the data values
        frequencyDataArray = new Uint8Array(analyserNode.frequencyBinCount);
        // Now connect the nodes together
        sourceNode.connect(audioContext.destination);
        sourceNode.connect(analyserNode);
        analyserNode.connect(javascriptNode);
        javascriptNode.connect(audioContext.destination);
    }

    function initCanvas() {
        ctx.fillStyle = 'hsl(280, 100%, 10%)';
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
    };

    // Play the audio once
    function playSound(buffer) {
        sourceNode.buffer = buffer;
        sourceNode.start(0);    // Play the sound now
        sourceNode.loop = false;
        audioPlaying = true;
    }

    function draw() {
        const data = frequencyDataArray;
        const dataLength = frequencyDataArray.length;
        console.log("data", data);

        const h = canvasHeight / dataLength;
        // draw on the right edge
        const x = canvasWidth - 1;

        // copy the old image and move one left
        let imgData = ctx.getImageData(1, 0, canvasWidth - 1, canvasHeight);
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
        ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);

        for (let i = 0; i < dataLength; i++) {
            // console.log(data)
            let rat = data[i] / 255;
            let hue = Math.round((rat * 120) + 280 % 360);
            let sat = '100%';
            let lit = 10 + (70 * rat) + '%';
            // console.log("rat %s, hue %s, lit %s", rat, hue, lit);
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.strokeStyle = `hsl(${hue}, ${sat}, ${lit})`;
            ctx.moveTo(x, canvasHeight - (i * h));
            ctx.lineTo(x, canvasHeight - (i * h + h));
            ctx.stroke();
        }
    }
});
```

## I explain shortly what each part does:

### creating audio context

When the DOM loads the `AudioContext` is created.

### loading the audio file and converting it to AudioBuffer

Then I load the sound from by backend server (the code is as shown above). The response is then converted to a buffer which is then decoded to an AudioBuffer. This is basically the main solution for the question above.

### Process AudioBuffer

To show a little bit more context how to use the loaded audio file I included the rest of the file.

To further process the AudioBuffer a source is created and the buffer is assigned to the source: `sourceNode.buffer = buffer`.

The `javascriptNode` acts IMHO like a stream where you can access the output of the analyzer.